# RxJava as an event bus, onNext is called multiple times when only one event post

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, event-bus

I'm implementing an event bus (RxBus) with RxJava.

**RxBus.java**

```
public class RxBus {

    private static final String TAG = LogUtils.makeTag(RxBus.class);
    private static final RxBus INSTANCE = new RxBus();

    private final Subject<Object, Object> mBusSubject = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.create());

    public static RxBus getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public <T> Subscription register(final Class<T> eventClass, Action1<T> onNext) {
        return mBusSubject
                .filter(new Func1<Object, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(Object event) {
                        return event.getClass().equals(eventClass);
                    }
                })
//                .filter(event -> event.getClass().equals(eventClass))
                .map(new Func1<Object, T>() {
                    @Override
                    public T call(Object obj) {
                        return (T) obj;
                    }
                })
//                .map(obj -> (T) obj)
                .subscribe(onNext);
    }

    public void post(Object event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Apr12, " + "post event: " + event);
        mBusSubject.onNext(event);
    }
}
```

**Post an event from viewHolder of a RecyclerView**

```
public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.bill_card, parent, false));

        drawee = (SimpleDraweeView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_title);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Apr12, item clicked.");
                RxBus.getInstance().post(new ItemSelectedEvent(position));
            }
        });

        TagImageButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tag_button);
        TagImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Tag button clicked.");
                RxBus.getInstance().post(new ApplyTagForItemEvent(position));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Subscribe the events from Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mActivity = getActivity();
    Log.d(TAG, "getActivity(): " + getActivity());
    mItemClickSubscription = RxBus.getInstance().register(ItemSelectedEvent.class,
            new Action1<ItemSelectedEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void call(ItemSelectedEvent event) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Apr12, " + "call event: " + event);
                    if (mDetail == null) {
                        if (getParentFragment() instanceof IFragmentStackHolder) {
                            IFragmentStackHolder fsh = (IFragmentStackHolder) getParentFragment();

                            Fragment details = new DetailCardFragment();
                            Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            args.putInt(ContentHolder.INDEX, event.getPosition());
                            details.setArguments(args);

                            fsh.pushFragment(details, event.getPairs());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    mApplyTagSubscription = RxBus.getInstance().register(ApplyTagForItemEvent.class,
            new Action1<ApplyTagForItemEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void call(ApplyTagForItemEvent event) {
                    IFragmentStackHolder fsh = (IFragmentStackHolder) getParentFragment();

                    Fragment tagApplyFragment = new TagApplyFragment();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt(ContentHolder.INDEX, event.getPosition());
                    tagApplyFragment.setArguments(args);

                    fsh.pushFragment(tagApplyFragment, null);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

The problem is: when I click on `itemView` or `TagImageButton`, `RxBus.post()` is only called once (which is correct), but `Action1 call()` is called multiple times (not even constant times). Please see the log below.

```
D/**-CardContentView(31177): Apr12, item clicked.
D/**-RxBus(31177): Apr12, post event: com.*****.events.ItemSelectedEvent@1a11346e
D/**-CardDetailFragment(31177): Apr12, call event: com.*****.events.ItemSelectedEvent@1a11346e
D/**-CardDetailFragment(31177): Apr12, call event: com.*****.events.ItemSelectedEvent@1a11346e
D/**-CardDetailFragment(31177): Apr12, call event: com.*****.events.ItemSelectedEvent@1a11346e
```

How can I make it called only once?

**EDIT:** I found that if `Action1 call()` is called N times this time, it will be called N+1 times next time when I click on the item. It seems that the the observable is emitting all subsequently observed items in the history to the subscriber.

Comment: How many `mItemClickSubscription` have you create?

Comment: @srain only one `mItemClickSubscription`. Actually `mItemClickSubscription` is not been used until `unsubscribe()`.

Comment: How many `Fragment` have you create? Where is your `unsubscribe()` method?

Comment: @srain Only this fragment is subscribing this event so far. I didn't call `unsubscribe()` yet. I plan to do `unsubscribe()` in `onDestroy()` or `onStop()`, but I think it has no influence on the error I got.

Comment: @srain holy crap... this is exactly where the problem is. I need to call `unsubscribe()` in `onStop()`, so that the previous handled event will not be emitted again. Thank you for your hint!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally find the solution.

Very simple: I should have called `mItemClickSubscription.unsubscribe();` and `mApplyTagSubscription.unsubscribe();` in `onStop()`.

[`PublishSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html) is used in the event bus. `PublishSubject` is a subject:

> Subject that, once an Observer has subscribed, emits all subsequently observed items to the subscriber.

So if you don't `unsubscribe()` the subscription, this subscription will keep "recording" all the events happened in the history, and emit all of them once `.subscribe(onNext)` is executed.

Comment: Awesome! I am having the same problem in android. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Isn't BehaviorSubject better choice here?